# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in reduce, np.sum result is inf

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, hdf5

I have two hdf5 files, the first file data shape is `(1, 10240)`, the np.sum value is 51260.0. the second file data shape is also `(1, 10240)`, the np.sum value is 51070.0. But when I read two files and append to a list, the np.sum result is `inf`, and report this info:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.14.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/_methods.py:32: 
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in reduce
  return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
```

Here is the code:

```
datas = []
for filename in os.listdir("path/"):
    filename = "path/" + filename
    data = h5py.File(filename)
    datas.append(list(data.get(key).value.reshape(-1)))
    data.close()
print np.sum(datas)
```

If I just read one file, the code is ok, and the `np.sum` result is also ok.

Why the `np.sum` is `inf` when I read two files?

Comment: Can you a add full traceback error

Comment: There is no error, but the `np.sum` result is `inf`, and report `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in reduce` @AnuragDhadse

Comment: Could you print the output of data[key].dtype? Also to debug you can first write to two variables (NumPy arrays) and inspect them

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing obviously wrong with your code. You can verify with this simple example. You used `.append` to create `datas` as a list of lists. I added a second way with `.extend()` to get a single list. Both give the same result.

```
arr1 = np.array([1,2,3])
arr2 = np.array([11,22,33])
datas = []
datas.append(list(arr1))
datas.append(list(arr2))
np.sum(datas)
Out[20]: 72

datas = []
datas.append(list(arr1.reshape(-1)))
datas.append(list(arr2.reshape(-1)))
np.sum(datas)
Out[25]: 72

datas = []
datas.extend(list(arr1.reshape(-1)))
datas.extend(list(arr2.reshape(-1)))
np.sum(datas)
Out[30]: 72
```

As noted in the comments, you need to verify dtype of `data[key]` of the HDF5 file. Here is a modified version of your code to do that. (Note: I modified the call to read the dataset; `data[key][:]` is simpler way to return a NumPy array compared to  `data.get(key).value`.)

```
datas = []
for filename in os.listdir("path/"):
    filename = "path/" + filename
    data = h5py.File(filename)
    print data[key].dtype
    arr = data[key][:]
    print arr.dtype, arr.shape, np.sum(arr)
    datas.append(list(arr.reshape(-1)))
    data.close()
print np.sum(datas)
```

Note: I am using Python 3.8 with NumPy 1.19.2, so there could be differences due to versions.

Comment: `data[key].dtype` and `arr.dtype` are `float16`, `np.sum(arr)` and `np.sum(datas)` are `inf`

Comment: You need to investigate why `np.sum(arr)` returns `inf`. That explains the error, but isn't consistent with your initial post. In it you said:"_`the first file np.sum is 51260.0. the second file np.sum is 51070.0`_". How did you get those values?